# Are two or more submit buttons in single form valid html?

Tags: html, forms, validation, button, input

A very basic example:

```
<form action="somephp.php" method="post">
```

... some stuff

```
<input type="submit" name="button1" value="value1" />
<input type="submit" name="button2" value="value2" />

<!-- or maybe even a third or fourth one ... hell knows -->
</form>
```

While I am well aware that this is possible, I have difficulties in finding documentation or specification, whether this is actually valid or allowed. What is common is one submit and maybe a reset button and that is it. I do not have to deal with this aspect on a daily basis, but now and then I do.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#forms
https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sec-forms.html#element-statedef-button-type-submit-button

There is a lot about forms, but not whether it is OK to use several buttons. It is indicated through the way a plural is avoided in terms of the submit button, that several for a single form is not what the standard has in mind.

Therefore, it would be really appreciated whether this aspect is something one should worry about and whether it could pose some problems. Links to points of references would be best. Thanks.

Comment: first question is why do you want to do that? it sounds anti pattern to me.

Comment: What's the scenario in which you need multiple submit buttons?

Comment: There is nothing in the spec that says you can't have more than 1 submit button. Its a perfectly sound way to setup a form with a limited set of choices.

Comment: General rule: Only one action (and one submit), otherwise what does return/enter/done/[default action] do? If you need to vary, do so with an option within the form (such as drop-down "action" field) or dedicated forms.

Comment: p.s. related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918666/is-putting-multiple-submit-buttons-on-an-html-form-bad-practice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from w3.org  "submit buttons: When activated, a submit button submits a form. A form may contain more than one submit button."

see [link](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#submit-button) for full text.

Answer (score 0):

One way to see if it's valid is to use a validator https://validator.w3.org

Looks like it's valid HTML5 https://i.stack.imgur.com/615nO.png

Answer (score 0):

I think it really doesn't matter if a form has a single Submit button or multiple Submit buttons with a post action. When the form method is Post, it simply posts the whole form data back to server. 
When it comes to technology like ASP.Net webforms, having multiple Submit buttons makes a difference, as each button can be linked to a different method that has to be executed in on the server-side but if you are using some platform where you just get the decide the form data and it's all upto you to decide how to process it based on the data state then having two submit buttons in a form is obviously redundant.